# Expanding tibble to full grid and keep all values

Tags: r, dplyr

If I have a data frame like below, is it possible to expand and keep all values (without overwriting the source tibble or saving the intermediate results)?

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- tibble(a = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b"),
            b = c("2019", "2020", "2021", "2019", "2020"),
            x = 1:5) %>%
  spread(key = b, value = x) # I did this on purpose because ..

# is it possible to simplify this?
d %>%
  gather(-a, key = "b", val = "x") %>% # .. otherwise I could just join
  expand(a, b) %>%
  left_join(d %>%
              gather(-a, key = "b", val = x),
            by = c("a", "b"))

# is it possible to do something like:
d %>%
  gather(-a, key = "b", val = "x") %>%
  expand(a, b, .keep_all = TRUE) # there is of course no .keep_all for expand

# want data set
# a     b         x
# <chr> <chr> <int>
#   1 a     2019      1
# 2 a     2020      2
# 3 a     2021      3
# 4 b     2019      4
# 5 b     2020      5
# 6 b     2021     NA
```

I am probably missing something, but I couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```r
d %>%
  spread(b, x) %>%
  gather(b, x, -a) %>%
  arrange(x)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  a     b         x
#  <chr> <chr> <int>
#1 a     2019      1
#2 a     2020      2
#3 a     2021      3
#4 b     2019      4
#5 b     2020      5
#6 b     2021     NA
```

Using `pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer`:

```r
d %>% pivot_wider(names_from = b, values_from = x) %>%
  pivot_longer(-a, names_to = "b", values_to = "x")

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   a     b         x
# <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1 a     2019      1
# 2 a     2020      2
# 3 a     2021      3
# 4 b     2019      4
# 5 b     2020      5
# 6 b     2021     NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure, maybe:

```
my_expand <- function(d, ...) {
  keep_vars = ensyms(...)
  expand(d, !!!keep_vars) %>%
    left_join(d, by = map_chr(keep_vars, expr_text))
}

d %>% 
  my_expand(a, b)

# a     b         x
# <chr> <chr> <int>
#   1 a     2019      1
# 2 a     2020      2
# 3 a     2021      3
# 4 b     2019      4
# 5 b     2020      5
# 6 b     2021     NA
```